# How to manually render the razor code of a parent component in blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

#### Introduction

I am trying to extend the functionality of the `MudTextField<T>` from the [mudblazor](https://mudblazor.com/components/textfield#api) library.
Usually I would create a wrapper, but since the behavior that I want to change is only available in protected methods, I chose to inherit the `MudTextField<T>` Component. The goal is to create a clone, only differing in the functionality that I change by overriding certain methods.

#### Inherited Component

So I've created a `CustomMudTextField<T>` Component.

**CustomMudTextField.razor**

```
@using System.Runtime.CompilerServices
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree
@inherits MudTextField<T>
@typeparam T

@code
{
    // omitted custom logic
}
```

The problem with this is, that the base Control doesn't get rendered anymore. So I tried to manually render the base class. I took inspiration from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

**CustomMudTextField.razor**

```
@using System.Runtime.CompilerServices
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree
@inherits MudTextField<T>
@typeparam T

@CustomRender

@code
{
    private RenderFragment CustomRender { get; set; }
    private RenderFragment RenderBase() => builder =>
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        CustomRender = RenderBase();
    }

    // omitted custom logic
}
```

I'd expect this to work just like the base component. Now the UI of the parent does get rendered, but the base functionality doesn't work at all.

I've also tried the approach discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21664), but the following code snippet doesn't even compile anymore.

```
@inherits BaseComponent
@{ 
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
```

---

#### So how can I render the content of the base control?

Other UI Frameworks use components, that can be used to render the base control. I'd expect this to work somehow similar to blazors [@ChildContent mechanic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#overwritten-parameters-1), even though its a whole other concept. Is there a way to inherit and render `MudTextField<T>` such that it will behave exactly the same way? **What am I missing?**

Comment: Try removing the `.razor` extension and just use a `.cs` class if your not changing the RenderFragment.

Answer (score 3):

If your not changing the renderfragment. You can simply create a new class `.cs` and inherit the component. As it does not use `.razor` it will not override the renderfragment.
For example:

`ComponentA.razor`

```
<h1>@Name</h1>
<button @onclick="DoSomething">Do Something</button>
@x
@code {
    protected  int x = 0;
    public virtual string Name {get;set;} = "ComponentA";
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        x = x + 1;    
    }
}
```

`ComponentB.cs`

```
    public class SomeComponentB : SomeComponentA
    {
        override public string Name {get;set;} = "ComponentB";
        
        override  public void DoSomething()
        {
            x = x + 2;    
        }
    }
```

ComponentB still inherits `ComponentBase` and can be used as a component.

```
<ComponentB />
```

Here is a working [REPL](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/mlOtGMFP53C3Oovj43)

Update:

Note: If you want to add content in the derived class, you can override the BuildRenderTree method like this:

```
 public class SomeComponentB : SomeComponentA
 {
      private string message = "A message from derived component";
      override public string Name {get;set;} = "ComponentB";
        
      override  public void DoSomething()
      {
            x = x + 2;    
      }
    

      protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
      {
           
          __builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
          __builder.AddContent(1, message);
          __builder.CloseElement();

          base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
      }
 }
```

Comment: hey there, it is indeed true, that this works in a codebehind change only scenario. thanks.
However I just figured out that my approach posted in the question, is indeed working. I'll soon post an example.

Comment: @LuckyLikey, We're still waiting to see your solution. In the meantime, would you please accept this answer till a better one surfaces.

Comment: @enet Thanks for the update. I updated the alignment and it removed your credit I didnt mean that...

Comment: It's nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that that `MudTextField` wasn't designed to be `inherited`.  It's  markup is defined as Razor, so any markup you add to the inherited component overrides the content in the parent.  You therefore must replicate the markup in your inherited component.  Sometimes you get lucky, but mostly you hit on `private` fields/properties and/or other class/field/property restrictions so you can't access them from your child component.

The markup for `MudTextField` looks like this:

```
<CascadingValue Name="Standalone" Value="@Standalone" IsFixed="true">
    <MudInputControl Label="@Label" Variant="@Variant" HelperText="@HelperText" HelperTextOnFocus="@HelperTextOnFocus" CounterText="@GetCounterText()" FullWidth="@FullWidth" Class="@Classname" Error="@HasErrors" ErrorText="@GetErrorText()" Disabled="@Disabled" Margin="@Margin" Required="@Required">
        <InputContent>
            <MudInput T="string" @ref="_elementReference" @attributes="UserAttributes" InputType="@InputType" Lines="@Lines" Style="@Style" Variant="@Variant" TextUpdateSuppression="@TextUpdateSuppression" Value="@Text" 
                      ValueChanged="(s) => SetTextAsync(s)" Placeholder="@Placeholder" Disabled=@Disabled DisableUnderLine="@DisableUnderLine" ReadOnly="@ReadOnly" MaxLength="@MaxLength"
                      Adornment="@Adornment" AdornmentText="@AdornmentText" AdornmentIcon="@AdornmentIcon" AdornmentColor="@AdornmentColor" IconSize="@IconSize" OnAdornmentClick="@OnAdornmentClick" Error="@Error" 
                      Immediate="@Immediate" Margin="@Margin" OnBlur="@OnBlurred" OnKeyDown="@InvokeKeyDown" OnInternalInputChanged="OnChange" OnKeyPress="@InvokeKeyPress" OnKeyUp="@InvokeKeyUp"
                      KeyDownPreventDefault="KeyDownPreventDefault" KeyPressPreventDefault="KeyPressPreventDefault" KeyUpPreventDefault="KeyUpPreventDefault"
                      HideSpinButtons="true" Clearable="@Clearable" OnClearButtonClick="@OnClearButtonClick" />
        </InputContent>
    </MudInputControl>
</CascadingValue>
```

I haven't gone all the way through it, but immediately I can see `@ref="_elementReference"` where `_elementReference` is private.

Comment: NP, I'm quite prepared to be wrong.  I learned that lesson a long, long time ago!  Explain?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in suggesting that you were wrong. I'll delete my comment, and upvote you.

Comment: @enet NP, I've done a lot of work with `IComponent` over the last few months so was intrigued to know a way to do it if you had one!

Comment: Not at the moment...sorry.